# Parsing .ini file into BeautifulSoup find_all() method

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
def test():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    #reading my .ini file
    config.read('config.ini')
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    #retrieving "data" from section "MarketPlace" 
    # data = "a" in this context
    data = config.get("MarketPlace", "data")
    #call soup.find_all to find "a"
    #Expect text = soup.find_all("a")
    text = soup.find_all(data)
    for everything in text:
        #print all text in wikipedia
        print(everything)
```

I am experimenting config file with the above method. The code are suppose to print all text, but nothing was printed. I am not sure why it doesn't work. As `data = "a"` i would assume that data in `soup.find_all(data)` to be `soup.find_all("a")` . Any one able to explain to me why this is happening? Or did i miss out something?

Comment: If `soup.find_all("a")` works and `soup.find_all(data)` doesn't, then clearly `data != "a"`. So print out `data` and see what it really is. Try `print(repr(data))` to make it easier to spot things like trailing spaces.

Comment: @smarx Thanks for your advice! You can put it as an answer, i will accept it.